# How to improve performance when using objects in Android

Tags: android, performance, object

I find that there is lag or a delay on some of my Android apps, and I've checked [the Android website](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips.html) to see how I could improve performance. However, the article mentioned avoiding using internal getters and setters. Would external getters and setters also slow down the performance speed of the app?

Ideally, I would like to keep using custom objects in my app (where I create an object and then call 'get' methods from it), so is there any way to improve performance but keep objects. Would it be more efficient to get an array of values and assigning each index of it to a variable, or should I have multiple get methods in my object, and assign variables to those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, there's nothing wrong with creating custom classes and is necessary in any app.  Before making an assumption like internal getters/setters being the source of the lag you are seeing, I would suggest profiling your app using [Traceview](https://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-tracing.html) and [Systrace](https://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/systrace.html).  This will help you identify the bottleneck in your app, rather than guessing at what could be the cause.

The discussion of getters/setters is strictly for internal getters/setters.  In other words, if you have a protected/private field called `mMyField` in your object, just reference it directly in code rather than using a private getter/setter.

Answer (score 2):

You are incorrectly interpreting the optimization tip.  It's reasonable to follow common object-oriented programming practices and have getters and setters in the *public interface*, but within a class you should always access *fields directly*.

Comment: if you use a proguard, the performance is the same as he will optimise your code to do direct calls.